# How to deal with or survive with the information overload

Tags: management, information

Every time I want to read something for example a book on Java, then I find so much stuff like many tutorials, many ebooks that I am not able to decide which one to choose.

I spend some time reading one, then two and so on and in the end I leave and gain nothing.

I like the old days when we had only few resources like one hard book and at least I finish that from start to finish and gained much but now days.

There is so much information that mind jumps from one source to other and gain nothing.

What should I do?

Comment: Balance between (1) learning (2) practicing (3) thinking (reflecting).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> there is so much information that mind jumps from one source to other and gain nothing
>
> what should i do

**Take it easy.**

You are in fact gaining knowledge. You read a tutorial, you learn something. You read another, you learn something new or maybe reinforce the info you've read in the first tutorial. You then read a book, and another... **one at a time**.

We work (sometimes live) in Information Technology. Information beeing the key word here. Lots and lots of information!

Even if there was only a book and you read that, in e few years it would be obsolete anyways. You always have to keep yourself up to date.

**Take it easy**

If you start reading all of them at once or want to read them all, you will get overwhelmed with info and then feel discouraged... which I think happened since you asked this question.

**Q: How do you eat an elephant? 
A: One bite at a time.**

**We all go through this.** When I was young I didn't have lots of info, books or tutorials so it was very hard to learn something or do something, it was always a struggle. Then I started gathering a lot of infos, tutorials, books etc to reduce the effort and now I have about one Terabyte of PDFs, DOCs, HTML files, CHMs etc. It will take me 50 life times to read them all so I don't even try.

1. Start with something, learn the basics
2. then go apply them. You will see that you are missing some info to get it done so goto step 1 with this new need for information.

At this point all documentation becomes a place to search inside for that missing info. Only that missing info! You will see it is much more manageable that trying to know everything.

Good luck!